# Create relationship between User and Addresses (1-Many) and Order and Address (1-1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a User class where each user can have multiple addresses.

I also have an Order class where each order can have exactly one address.

I have the following code and am getting cascade delete errors, prior to this I was getting foreign key constraint issues and have fixed these already.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I am unsure what is wrong now, I assume the cascade issue is with my attempt to implement the 1-1 and 1-Many relationship on the address table.

The exact error is this:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 
'FK_dbo.Purchases_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId' on table 
'Orders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify 
other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

I am getting this error when executing this statement in the Visual Studio 2013 Package Manager Console.

```
'Update-Package -Force'
```

**Edit:**

After following @erkaners suggestions I am starting to rethink this structure.

A 'User' can have as many delivery addresses as they want. Some of our users ship to multiple addresses often and shouldn't have to repeatedly type these adresses in.

An 'Order' is an in-progress order and the customer selects one of their previous addresses, or enters a new one when this order is created.

I then have a table for 'OrderHistory' which is completed orders.

Now I'm thinking I dont actually ever want an address deleted because then the 'OrderHistory' table won't be able to refer to its address anymore.

Instead I think I should be adding a boolean column to mark addresses Active/Inactive and drop the cascade delete completely. Is this a better course of action?

Comment: use inheritance for `Order`

Comment: How would inheritance help with order? The final order history is quite different from the order, some properties do not transfer to the history as they are only required pre-purchase.

Answer (score 3):

This is because there are two paths that can cause the deletion of an address. Using the fluent api you can solve this problem:

```
  public class Order
  {
      public string OrderId { get; set; }

      [Required, ForeignKey("User")]
      public string UserId { get; set; }
      public virtual User User { get; set; }

      [Required, ForeignKey("Address")]
      public int AddressId { get; set; }
      public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
  }

  public class Address
  {     
      public int AddressId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("User")]
      public string UserId { get; set; }
      public User User { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("Order")]
      public string OrderId { get; set; }
      public Order Order { get; set; }
  }


  modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
              .HasMany(u => u.Addresses)
              .WithRequired(a => a.User)
              .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Cheers, do i need to remove any of the data annotations or will the fluent api override it?

Comment: @Hellfire do not worry about the other parts, the relationships would work without fluent api, but we need it here for `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: Ok cool, also should it be Entity<Order> ? Just wondering why the user has a foreign key to a user ;) 
 
If I delete a user I want the cascade, but If i delete an order I dont want it

Comment: Now i get 4 errors on IdentityUser (No keys defined) and this one: Order_Address_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Order_Address_Source' in relationship 'Order_Address'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: @Hellfire can you see the class definitions above, and discard the fluent api for now?

Comment: Won't this cause Primary key problems when the user has mutiple addresses? See the edit to my question above for way more detail.